# PC not wake up after suspend

Tags: release-hera, suspend

My intel NUC not waking up after automatic suspend.
i use wireless mouse and keyboard. Pc not wake up after pressing keyboard or mouse.
also not wake up after pressing the power button.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the Help Center for Elemtary OS and not Intel for NUCs, so you are in the wrong place.

But having a lot of experience in NUC you have to look at your settings in the BIOS of the NUC for USB and Wake Up by USB.

This [link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005522/intel-nuc.html) can help you

Thank you